# vaadin strange bug when run application

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

```
2023-05-18T12:54:22.736+02:00  INFO 20376 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-18T12:54:22.738+02:00  INFO 20376 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2093 ms
2023-05-18T12:54:22.934+02:00 ERROR 20376 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-24.0.6.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-24.0.6.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-24.0.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4452) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4892) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at it.unidoc.cdr.core.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

i have this problem when run in intellij and jdk 17 on windows11

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: If you check the logs you will probably find a message like "Found app shell configuration annotations in non AppShellConfigurator classes", and following the list of the annotation that should be moved